# Can we do session management without form submission in JSP?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I am creating a small web application for learning purpose. Here I use Java, Jquery ,Ajax . I want to add sessions to my project . I am not using forms (request is not via form submission) in JSP. I have updated my code here. Can someone give me a solution for adding sessions to my application using Jquery Ajax request.

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
            var username=document.getElementById("uname").value;
            var password=document.getElementById("psw").value;
            if (username=="" || username == null || password == ""|| password == null){
                alert("Please input values");
                document.getElementById("username").focus();
            } else {
                var method;
                $.ajax({
                    type : 'post',
                    url : 'userservlet',
                    data : {
                        username : username,
                        password : password,
                        method : "login",
                    },
                    success: function (responseText) {
                        if (responseText.success){

                        }
                        else {
                            alert(responseText.error);

                        }
                    }
                });
            }   
        });
```

Login

**Backend when I used form submission**

```
public String loginuser(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String username, String password) throws IOException {
    HttpSession httpSession = request.getSession();
    UserDAOImpl userdaoimpl = new UserDAOImpl();
    String sts=null;

    try {
         sts = userdaoimpl.loginUser(username,password);
         httpSession.setAttribute("username", username);
         httpSession.setAttribute("password", password);

         //httpSession.setMaxInactiveInterval(60);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sts;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are stored on the server, so you can't do that using client side technologies like Jquery or Ajax. You will need server side programming for that.(Java in your case). Please try to understand first, you are indirectly submitting the form, the option to do that you have chosen Ajax (asynchronous), instead of the traditional form-action. Sessions will be handled in your Java code. (UserServlet), By seeing your code, I can understand that you are passing username and password to your servlet, set the session in your servlet and send response from your servlet, which will be handled after ajax call success/failure.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me to understand this flow. I updated my Java code related to login in question. But I removed Ajax request to form submission to do this in my application. My understanding was we were able to add sessions (httpsession) only if we use form submission. Is this understanding incorrect @5eeker

Comment: No, it directly doesn't handles that, we need to do it.

Comment: Could you please share me a link or any document related to this?

Comment: Login Example with Servelt : https://www.journaldev.com/1907/java-session-management-servlet-httpsession-url-rewriting